# i cant put The body in center?

Tags: html, css

I Have Html And Css Tags . My problem is That I want To us My body In center of page ?
and also i dont want to use Center tags ?
there is my tags

```
body {
    background-image:url(../Image/bg1.jpg);
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    padding-top:10px;
}
/*Header Start*/
 .Header {
    background-color:red;
    width:801px;
    height:141px;
}
.Logo {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:block;
}
.socialapp {
    display:inline;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
/*Header End*/
 .content {
    background-color:yellow;
    width:800px;
    height:1000px;
}
.footer {
    background-color:green;
    width:800px;
    height:138px;
}
```

my whole problem is Body Tag !!
Please help me

Comment: add a width to your body and margin auto

Comment: You've left the width of the `body` at `auto` so it is going to be as wide as the window (well, the HTML element, which comes to the same thing in this case). What difference would you expect centring it to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add some width to your body tag presently its auto.
add `margin:auto`

```
body {
    background-image:url(../Image/bg1.jpg);
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    padding-top:10px;

    width:800px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

**or**
**create a wrapper div inside body tag:**

**html:**

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        your header,content, footer etc code here...    
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper{
    width:800px;
    margin:auto;
}
```